# Add string to mysql result

Tags: mysql, string, addition

I need mySql result with some prefixes and suffixes. This is my code:

```
SELECT bk_id, bk_rtype, villas_db.v_name AS villa_name
FROM booking_db
INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_db.bk_vid = villas_db.v_id
WHERE '2012-11-02'
BETWEEN bk_date1
AND bk_date2
ORDER BY bk_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The result are:

```
bk_id   bk_rtype    villa_name
30          2           T2
29          3           V1
```

So I need the result as:

```
bk_id   bk_rtype    villa_name     booking_no
30          2           T2         B2-00030
29          3           V1         B3-00029
```

While B is a booking prefix separate by "-" and sprintf("%05d",bk_id);

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution:

```
SELECT bk_id, bk_rtype, villas_db.v_name AS villa_name, concat( 'B', bk_rtype, '-', lpad( bk_id, 5, 0 ) ) AS booking_no
FROM booking_db
INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_db.bk_vid = villas_db.v_id
WHERE '2012-11-02'
BETWEEN bk_date1
AND bk_date2
ORDER BY bk_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: How it is different than my answer?

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use `CONCAT` and `LPAD` functions as below:

```
 SELECT bk_id, bk_rtype, villas_db.v_name AS villa_name, 
        CONCAT('B',bk_rtype,'-', LPAD(bk_id, 5, '0')) AS booking_no
 FROM booking_db
 INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_db.bk_vid = villas_db.v_id
 WHERE '2012-11-02'
     BETWEEN bk_date1
     AND bk_date2
 ORDER BY bk_id DESC 
 LIMIT 0 , 30 ;
```

Comment: your answer is good but a bit close to the best. I found my solution anyway.

Comment: @Wilf: How your solution is different than my answer?

Comment: @RocketDonkey: Thanks for highlighting. In fact I answered 10+ minutes before the response. OP says, he got the solution but I couldn't notice the difference :)

Comment: Haha, I've had that happen before too - I spent 10 minutes scratching my head until I realized that there was no difference at all :)

Comment: Appreciated for both of you. The point of the different is I use "LPAD" for the leading zeros (while your code was '000' - before you're edited) and having the number not more than 5 digits. In fact I tried googled these solution while I left a question here. But yeah, your solution is also right. Regards.

Comment: @Wilf: That's correct, but even the edit using `LPAD` was made soon after posting the answer(before your input). Anyway, your problem is resolved, that's the good thing. Enjoy :-)